# Can not get rid of Key Lookup in the explain plan

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get rid of the Key Lookup operation in the explain plan of the following query:

```
            SELECT  s.CompanyId ,
                    t.PeriodEndDate ,
                    t.DurationId ,
                    s.conceptid AS SConceptId ,
                    c.ConceptId AS CConceptId,
                    t.NumOfPeriods ,
                    cast(cast(s.Value as numeric) as varchar(100)) as Value,
                    s.ConceptId * 17.0 AS ConceptOrdering , 
                    t.CompoundSortKeyLogicalKey,
                    1980 + (s.NumberOfQuarters / 4) AS FiscalYear,
                    (s.NumberOfQuarters % 4) + 1 AS FiscalQuarter,
                    cam.Alias
            FROM    [dbo].[TmpCompanyOrderedAndFilteredPKs] t
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[synt_ScreenerDb_dbo_ScreenerHistoricalYTD_Number_t] s ON s.CompanyId = t.CompanyId
                                                          AND s.numberofquarters = t.numberofquarters  AND ( ( t.numberOfQuarters % 4 ) + 1 ) = 4 
                    INNER JOIN [##FinancialsConcepts7FD96D75-FCDB-44B0-9DED-6FE0BC128982] c ON c.ConceptMapId = s.ConceptId
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.ConceptAliasMapping cam ON cam.ConceptId = c.ConceptId
            WHERE   t.OperationGUID = '7FD96D75-FCDB-44B0-9DED-6FE0BC128982'
```

The screenshot of the explain plan:
[image]

I've tried to create indexes on following columns:

```
Value, ConceptId, CompanyId, NumberOfQuarters
```

with different combination on INDEX and INCLUDE columns. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many performance ussues in your query. Follow the steps mentioned below to avoid key Lookups.

Include all the columns in the select statement in non clustered index

```
        create nonclustered index ncli_1 on TmpCompanyOrderedAndFilteredPKs(CompanyId)
        include(PeriodEndDate,DurationId ,NumOfPeriods,CompoundSortKeyLogicalKey,numberofquarters )

        create nonclustered index ncli_2 on synt_ScreenerDb_dbo_ScreenerHistoricalYTD_Number_t(CompanyId)
        include(conceptid ,Value ,NumberOfQuarters )

        create nonclustered index ncli_3 on ##FinancialsConcepts7FD96D75-FCDB-44B0-9DED-6FE0BC128982(ConceptId)

    `create unique clustered index cli_4 on ##FinancialsConcepts7FD96D75-FCDB-44B0-9DED-6FE0BC128982(ConceptMapId)` -- This will make sql server use 
merge join` instead of hash join which will provide performance gain.
```

Comment: just create nonclustered index IX__ScreenerHistoricalYTD_Number_t_CompanyId on ScreenerHistoricalYTD_Number_t(CompanyId)
        --include(conceptid ,Value ,NumberOfQuarters ) was enough